# How to whitelist origin for okta auth token validation on CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, okta

I have resources hosted on S3 and I am accessing those through CloudFront. I want to whitelist one site to access resource hosted on S3 and CloudFront and do not perform auth token validation. Is there a way to whitelist?